# MongoDB Atlas logs to Grafana/Loki Cloud

Tags: mongodb, grafana, mongodb-atlas, grafana-loki

Im using Grafana Cloud to capture logs and metrics from Kubernetes cluster. One of parts of the infrastructure is MongoDB in Atlas. I was able to capture metrics from that Mongo by using MongoDB Atlas integration found in Connections panel but I wanna capture logs too and show them directly in Grafana. Is that possible, if yes then how?

I did not find any information about logs in MongoDB Atlas, except exporting it manually via UI or creating some export jobs and using API but it looks like it is not native in Grafana.